# How to create subscription service using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, subscription

I am working on a Django application. I need to include subscription service in the application. I am using the fields `is_subscribed`, `subscription_start` and `subscription_end` in the `user profile` models. I am using Razorpay for the payment integration. After successful payment I am updating the subscription status as follows:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(is_subscribed=True,subscription_start=datetime.datetime.now(),subscription_end=datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days))
```

How to update the `UserProfile` automatically as soon the `subscription_end` is less than the current time. I want the model to be updated as `is_subscribed` as False as soon as the time is over. As of now, whenever a user visits any url, I am checking whether the user's subscription is valid. If not , then I am updating the model in this way

```
user = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()


 use1 = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user,subscription_end__gte=datetime.datetime.now()).values()
 if not use1[0]['is_admin']:
     UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(is_subscribed=False,joined=[])
```

. what is the correct way to update as soon as the subscription ends.

Comment: I believe you would need to create a management command and call it from a cron (maybe everyday at midnight).

Comment: But what if someone's subscription ends in between two midnights(suppose). He can still access the functionalities

Comment: Then you could set your cron to be triggered every minutes but I think it would be better to have an event based trigger like the answer by @radwan-abu-odeh

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of **RazorPay** [Webhooks](https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/), specifically [Subscriptions Webhooks](https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/payloads/#subscriptions).

You need to configure your **RazorPay** account to trigger your subscription event and specify your Django App's Endpoint that is going to handle that specific event. You need to build your own endpoint that is going to handle that event when it is triggered. [[Follow This Guide to configure your **RazorPay** Account]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtsvGEB7n0s)

The webhook event you need to be waiting for is `subscription.pending`.